# Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type SessionStore found

Tags: swift, firebase, observableobject

I receive the following error message: Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type SessionStore found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for SessionStore may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type SessionStore found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for SessionStore may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file SwiftUI, line 0

But I already have added the enviromentObject(SessionStore()) to the preview. So I don't get why  is this happening.

Here is my ContentView file:

```
    import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import LinkKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    func getUser() {
        session.listen()
    }
    @State private var showingSheet = true
    
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    @StateObject private var manager = FirebaseManager()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if (session.session != nil && manager.profilePicExists == true) {
                HostingTabView()
            } else if (session.session != nil && manager.profilePicExists == false){
                HostingTabView().sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                    RegistrationProfileDataView()
                }
            } else {
                AuthView()
           }
        }.onAppear(perform: getUser)
        .onAppear(perform: manager.checkForProfileImage)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(SessionStore())
    }
}
```

Here is the SessionStore file file:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import Combine

class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
     var didChange =  PassthroughSubject<SessionStore, Never>()
    @Published var session: User? {didSet {self.didChange.send(self) }}
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
    func listen() {
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                self.session = User(uid: user.uid, email: user.email)
            } else {
                self.session = nil
            }
        })
    }
    
    func signUp(email: String, password: String, handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handler)
    }
    
    func signIn(email: String, password: String, handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handler)
    }
    
    func signOut() {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            self.session = nil
        } catch {
            print("Error signing out")
        }
    }
    
    func unbind() {
        if let handle = handle {
            Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        unbind()
    }
    
}

struct User {
    var uid: String
    var email: String?
    
    init(uid: String, email: String?) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.email = email
    }
}
```

Comment: You added that to the preview, but did you add that to the actual app?

Comment: @aheze where exactly do you mean?

Comment: To build on @aheze's question, is this error happening when running the preview or running on a simulator/device?

Comment: @NikolaS. like when you are instantiating a `ContentView` in your actual app, for example in `YourApp_App.swift` or `SceneDelegate.swift`, did you attach a `environmentObject(SessionStore())`?

Comment: The app builds successfully. When it reaches the line with the if statement "session.session != null" it throws the error. I'm running the app on my physical iPhone device. The preview doesn't load because it cannot render the view, because it crashes when checking the if statement.

Comment: @aheze Thank you. It appears that was causing the error. I've added it to the sceneDelegate.swift and it now doesn't throw the error. Unfortunately when checking manager.profilePicExists == true it enters the function and throws: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. This is happening when executing:  let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid so weird.

Comment: @NikolaS. that means `Auth.auth().currentUser` is nil